# How can i access my docker website on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nuxt.js

I build a website with Nuxt and turn it locally into a docker image and push it to docker HUB after i pull the docker image from docker HUB to an amazon web server from there i run my docker image so nuxt start here http://172.17.0.2:3000/  but now i wonder how can i access the website like from an url or point a domain name to it ?
Coz even locally i need to remove 172.17.0.2 and put localhost instead.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT

Thank you for the quick answers i tried what you both told me and when i use docker inspect  i got this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ5yF.png)

I must have something wrong in my dockerfile maybe :

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:lts-alpine

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends on how you are running the container on the ec2 instance:

```
docker run -d -p 80:3000 docker-image
```

where:

-d option specifies that the container runs in detached mode: the container continues to run until stopped but does not respond to commands run on the command line.

-p option tells Docker to map the ports exposed in the container by the docker-image image (port 3000) to the specified port on the Docker host(ec2 isntance).

The first parameter specifies the port in the Docker host, the second parameter is mapped to the port exposed in the container.

Now you can verify if this is working by:

```
curl localhost
```

Once you are sure the index page is loading fine you grab the public IP address of the [instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#working-with-ip-addresses) from the console or via [AWS Cli](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html) and use that for accessing the website.

Make sure your security group attached to the instance is allowing the port 80 traffic.